# Menu toggle not working on mobile, but works in all mobile simulators in desktop browsers

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, menu, hamburger-menu

so on https://www.charitygolfsigns.com/ I have the menu collapsing into a hamburger menu icon for mobile, but tapping on it does nothing on my phone and other people's phones. Yet it works when clicking on it on mobile simulators in Google Chrome DevTools and when shrinking the normal browser window.

I've been taking the WordPress additional CSS out and back in but it doesn't shed any light on where the problem is.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right now i dont see anything on that site, that could toggle your menu at all (even in the DevTools).

You can add a simple jquery Script, that toggles your menu:

```
<script>
   jQuery('.header-mobile-menu').click(function() {
     jQuery('#site-navigation').toggle();
   });
</script>
```

But even if that toggles your navigation - you still need a style for it or toggle an individual block for mobile. Because right now, it would only toggle your "Desktop" Navigation